# Speed Calculator using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, time, distance

Can someone help me to fix my error. I am making a speed calculator. Is it the wrong usage or variables or is the function code wrong. I am very sorry if this question is silly as I have just started learning javascript.

```js
let distance = document.getElementById('distance');
let hours = document.getElementById('speed');
function calculate() {
    let formula = distance / time;
    para.textContent = 'average speed : ' + formula;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Enter these values:</h1><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form>
      <h2>Enter distance</h2><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="distance" name="distance" placeholder="Enter distance"><br>
      <br>
      <h2>Enter time</h2><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="time" name="times" placeholder="Enter time taken">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Average Speed" onclick="calculate()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1 id="answer">Answer:</h1>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be quite a few problems with the code which will also produce errors and cause the calculator to not work. But the error that's occurring right now is "Uncaught ReferenceError: para is not defined."
It seems like you are trying to display the output/answer to the  with the id "answer".
(I'm assuming) You forgot to add

```
let para = document.getElementById('answer');
```

at the start of the script.
And the other problem with your code is:

```
let formula = distance / time;
```

here, "distance" is a variable that contains an element , you have to use "distance.value"
to get the actual value of the  element.

final solution:

```
let distance = document.getElementById('distance');
let hours = document.getElementById('time');
let para = docment.getElementById('answer');
function calculate() {
    let formula = distance.textContent / time.textContent;
    para.textContent = 'average speed : ' + formula;
}
```